# First order logic. Independent set of sentences.

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $\Delta$ be a finite, consistent set of first-order sentences and $\Sigma$ be a finite signature. Prove that there exists such $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta $ that $\Delta_0 \models \Delta$ and : for every $\phi \in \Delta_0 , \Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \not \models \Delta_0 $

I tried to do it. I am asking for hint.

$$ \Delta \text{ is independent iff for every } \phi \in \Delta_0, \Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \not \models \Delta_0$$

**Solution:**

**Base induction**

Let $|\Delta| = 0, \Delta = \emptyset$. $\emptyset \models \Delta, \emptyset$ is indenpendent.

**Induction step**
Let $|\Delta| = n $ and $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta, \Delta_0 \models \Delta, \Delta_0 $ is independent.
Let's consider two cases:

Let $\Delta' = \Delta \cup \{\phi\} $ for any $\phi$

1. $\Delta_0 \models \{\phi\}$. Then $\Delta_0 \models \Delta' $ and $\Delta_0 $ is still independent
2. $\Delta_0 \not \models \{\phi\}$
   Let $\Delta_0' = \Delta_0 \cup \{\phi\}$. Then $\Delta_0' \models \Delta' $ Now, let consider two cases:

   2.1 $\Delta_0'$ is independent. Thesis.

   2.2 $\Delta_0'$ is not independent. Therefore, there exists a such $\psi \in \Delta_0 $ that $\Delta_0' \setminus \{\psi \} \models \Delta_0'$.
   Let $\Gamma = \Delta_0' \setminus \{\psi\}$.
   Note, that $|\Gamma| \le |\Delta|$.
   So, from the inductive assumption, we have that there exists a such $\sigma \subseteq \Gamma $  that $\sigma \models \Gamma $ and $\sigma$ is independent. $\sigma \models \Gamma, \Gamma \models \Delta_0' $ so $\sigma  \models \Delta_0'$

Is it ok?

Comment: Hello - welcome to the site.  Posts that merely pose a problem, without context, are discouraged (indeed, they are often indistinguishable from copies of homework problems) There is some advice at this link about how to write a good post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . You can edit your post at any time to improve it. Information that could be included: where did the problem arise? What is your interpretation of it? What have you attempted already?

Comment: The main hint I can think of is to use induction. What have you tried?

Comment: Ok, good idea- I wil try to use induction, but why do I should- after all- sets are finite?

Comment: @Logic Carl means induction *on the size of $\Delta$*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible hint, expanding on Carl Mummert's and answering the question, "Why induction?" is this:

Let $P(n)$ stand for the claim that every finite, consistent set $\Delta$ of $n$ sentences from a first-order language with signature $\Sigma$ contains an independent subset $\Delta_0$.  Your problem consists of proving $\forall n . P(n)$.  Therefore induction is the natural approach to the proof.  Each $n$ is finite, but you want a proof for all $n$.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: It's a good start.  You may want to work on the wording.  For instance, "Now let $n>0$ and $\Delta = \Delta' \cup \{\phi\}$ with $\phi \not\in \Delta'$. By the induction hypothesis,..."

Comment: Is it correct or not?

Comment: It's close.  For instance, when you say, "Let \Delta' = \Delta \cup \{\phi\}$ for **any** $\phi$," you actually mean "some $\phi$."  Rewriting the proof as I suggested in my previous post would take care of some of these details.  Also, switching from uppercase ($\Delta$, $\Gamma$) to lowercase ($\sigma$) is not a mistake, but should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I meant **some** instead **any**. So, generally it is ok, yeah?

Comment: It's generally OK.  If the question really is, "Will I get full credit for it?" then the answer is, "It depends on who's grading, and the level of the course you are in."  Ask yourself, "How come removing one $\psi$ guarantees independence?"

Comment: I cannot grasp what do you mean by "How come removing one $\psi$ guarantees independence?"" After all, it doesn't guarentees independence.

Comment: You are right.  I misread your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Among finite subsets of $\Delta$, there are some of them that satisfy $\Delta_0 \vDash \Delta$, and some of them that do not. Pick one that is *minimal*: $\Delta_0 \vDash \Delta$, but for all $\Delta_0' \subsetneq \Delta_0$, $\Delta_0' \not \vDash \Delta$.

Now you have to prove that for any $\phi \in \Delta_0$, $\Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \not \vDash \Delta_0$.
Suppose towards contradiction that $\Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \vDash \Delta_0$. Then we have $\Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \vDash \Delta_0$ and $\Delta_0 \vDash \Delta$, so $\Delta_0 \setminus \{\phi\} \vDash \Delta$. This contradicts the minimality of $\Delta_0$.

Comment: I edited my post